# How to check if a role already exists in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

**How to check if a role already exist in discord.py**

I am trying a command which creates a role, but if the role already exist the code won't create a new role.

```py
@bot.command()
async def modrole(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    if guild.has_role(name="BotMod"):
        await ctx.send("Role already exists")
    else:
        await guild.create_role(name="BotMod", colour=discord.Colour(0x0062ff))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `discord.utils.get` to iterate through `ctx.guild.roles` to find one with that name:

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command()
async def modrole(ctx):
    if get(ctx.guild.roles, name="BotMod"):
        await ctx.send("Role already exists")
    else:
        await ctx.guild.create_role(name="BotMod", colour=discord.Colour(0x0062ff))
```